# iFrame app.. redirect back to page tab after user authorizes the app

Tags: facebook, redirect

I am having a lot of trouble getting my facebook app to redirect back to a tab on a page once the user authorizes it.

My app will live on multiple pages so its not as easy as pasting a url in for the redirect. Is there a way to grab the page's id and place that into the redirect url? Here is my code...

```
<?php  
session_start();

 //facebook application configuration -mahmud
$fbconfig['appid' ] = "xxx";
$fbconfig['secret'] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$fbconfig['baseUrl']    =   "http://localhost/foods/";
$fbconfig['appBaseUrl'] =   ""; //Need page tab url here


/* 
 * If user first time authenticated the application facebook
 * redirects user to baseUrl, so I checked if any code passed
 * then redirect him to the application url 
 * -mahmud
 */
if (isset($_GET['code'])){
    //header("Location: " . $fbconfig['appBaseUrl']);
   // exit;
}
//~~

//
if (isset($_GET['request_ids'])){
    //user comes from invitation
    //track them if you need
}

$user            =   null; //facebook user uid
try{
    include_once "facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($o);
    echo '</pre>';
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$user       = $facebook->getUser();
// We may or may not have this data based 
// on whether the user is logged in.
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
// the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don’t know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //you should use error_log($e); instead of printing the info on browser
    d($e);  // d is a debug function defined at the end of this file
    $user = null;
  }
}

if (!$user) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
    exit;
}

//get user basic description
$userInfo           = $facebook->api("/$user");

function d($d){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($d);
    echo '</pre>';
}



$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$page_id = $signed_request['page']['id'];



$_SESSION['pageID']=$page_id; 

$_SESSION['userID'] = $user;


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out this line:
echo "top.location.href = '$loginUrl';";

I believe the default behavior for logging in on a tab page is to remain on that tab page. You don't have to tell it to go there.

Comment: I commented that out but my app just doesn't load now.

Comment: Whenever I remove all mentions about a redirect it sends me to my app's page with a few query strings

http://localhost/foods/?state=05efbcc4c5bf591e56f518ee16a375ce&code=AQCAlYQpbJmCttiE7nDCxCVOWB6gAg51hpb4LTj2g5zmvylE6_p0sJ8BDRoHH7Z1jwncnUwJGbl-2e-ku8sN9773iIBvlXFdo7EM6Vc3hNYzC9Lg3X9xhnmExkHg6hNeZadc2VoVQ82PtRXKW-oh3m30tb3GnOqXcLlQKMldZvomEDvKssp8iPflAIDqOdmR2Ik#_=_